# How can I store values from a method into database?

Tags: c#

I have a method which takes the checked value(there can be 2 or more and the value's name is courseName) from the view and stores it in a collection called "SelectedCourses".The problem in this case is that i don't know if I should store the courseName value in the RegisterTeacher table where i store all the other values or in a separate table named Course.These are the 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses] (
[courseName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[SNTeacher]  INT            NOT NULL,
[education]  NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[ClassID]    NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[courseID]   INT            NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([courseID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Courses_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([SNTeacher]) REFERENCES [dbo].[RegisterTeacher] ([SNTeacher])
```

);

And this is table RegisterTeacher:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RegisterTeacher] (
[SNTeacher]  INT            NOT NULL,
[UserName]   NVARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
[pwd]        INT            NOT NULL,
[fullName]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[CourseName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[courseID]   INT            NULL,
[education]  NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SNTeacher] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_RegisterTeacher_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([courseID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Courses] ([courseID])
```

);

My question is how am I going to store the courses from the collection SelectedCourses and,in case I need to store them in a separate table,will the join syntax work in this case?Any help or advice would be appreciated.
This is the method for storing the values into the db:

```
   public void SaveTeacher(object param)
    {
   string connectionString = null;
        string sql = null;
        connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\BackupVersion\\LastAndFinalVersion\\DatabaseStudents.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sql = "Insert into RegisterTeacher(SNTeacher,UserName,pwd,fullName,CourseName,education)values(@SNTeacher,@_UserName,@pwd,@fullName,@courseName,@education)";
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SNTeacher", SNTeacher);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", _UserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", pwd);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullName", fullName);
                SelectedCourses = new ObservableCollection<Cours>();
                foreach (var item in Courses)
                {

                    if (item.IsChecked)
                    {
                        SelectedCourses.Add(item);

                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", courseName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@education", education);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registration succesfull! ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need a junction table RegisterTeachersToCourses in which to save the teacher id and the course id

Comment: Ok @Alexandru ,I understand but do I have to make a separate query for inserting the SelectedCourses values or in the same query I join the 2 columns?

Comment: You should make a different query for inserting into RegisterTeachersToCourses for sure since it's different functionality. And I suggest moving your queries to stored procedures so that they can be reused and that way you can modify them at any time without the need to rebuild your code.

Comment: Got it, @AlexandruPopa!Thank you for your help :)